# localhost not reading htaccess, httpd AllowOverride All causes error

Tags: .htaccess, apache

I am newbie trying to duplicate my online site on to a local server using Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.15.  However, my localhost isn't reading the .htaccess file.  I modified the example httpd.conf file and it registers the site correctly starting with localhost/index.php.  But if I goto localhost/index I get a "Not Found" error.  The .htaccess file works fine through my ISP (i.e. mysite.com/index works without a problem).

At first I thought it was a problem with my .htaccess rewrite
    
    `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`
    `RewriteEngine on`
    `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /$1\.php$2 [L]`

But my localhost isn't reading the 404 error either which lead me to think it is the httpd.conf file.  After some research a found a similar problem happens when the AllowOverride isn't switched to 'All'. Here is the what I had.

```
<Directory "D:/mywebfile/webserver/website/public_html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I switch it to AllOverride All, I get an "Internal Server Error" with the following log error

> httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.99.35 for ServerName [Sat Aug 04 15:15:55 2012] [notice] Child 9152: Child process is running 
>   [Sat Aug 04 15:15:55 2012] [notice] Child 9152: Acquired the start mutex. 
>   [Sat Aug 04 15:15:55 2012] [notice] Child 9152: Starting 64 worker threads. 
>   [Sat Aug 04 15:15:55 2012] [notice] Child 4764: Released the start mutex 
>   [Sat Aug 04 15:15:56 2012] [notice] Child 4764: All worker threads have exited. 
>   [Sat Aug 04 15:15:56 2012] [notice] Child 4764: Child process is exiting 
>   [Sat Aug 04 15:15:56 2012] [notice] Child 9152: Starting thread to listen on port 80. 
>   [Sat Aug 04 15:15:58 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] D:/mywebfile/mywebserver/website/public_html/.htaccess: >Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I have also tried to uncomment

> `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

in the httpd file but I still get the same "Internal Server Error"

This seems like a simple problem but I've exhausted all my simple solutions. Any help will be greatly appreciated (and save me what little hair I haven't pulled out).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `RewriteEngine` command, not `AllowOverride`. That just *activates* the rewrite command.

Activating mod_rewrite is the way to go, the way you show. Make sure you are editing the right httpd.conf file and that you restart the server before trying again.

Comment: You set me on the right track. I figured it had to do with the AllowOverride after I enabled the rewrite_mod and it still didn't work but my .htaccess had some other commands (headers and expires) that weren't enabled in the httpd.conf. All I had to do was activate them and then do a fist pump.

I can't thank you enough!!